# Using std::variant with std::ranges algorithms

Tags: c++, c++20

I have some predicate objects that take some value and return the result of some criteria. (My real implementation is more complex, this is only a minimal example):

[Run on Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cMTPzdf1o)

```
struct PredEven
{
    bool passes(int x) const { return x%2 == 0; }
};
struct PredGreaterThan
{
    int limit;
    bool passes(int x) const { return x > limit; }
};
using Predicate = std::variant<PredEven, PredGreaterThan>;
```

I store objects of these types in a `std::array` and now want to test some value against all of these.
The straight-forward implementation would be this:

```
const std::array<Predicate, 2> predicates = {PredEven{}, PredGreaterThan{3}};
const int valToTest = 4;

bool allPassed1 = true;
for(const auto& var : predicates)
{
    allPassed1 &= std::visit([&valToTest](const auto& p){ return p.passes(valToTest); }, var);
}
```

However, I really should be using std::all_of for this. Better yet, the ranges version:

```
const bool allPassed2 = std::ranges::all_of(predicates, [&valToTest](const auto& var)
    { return std::visit([&valToTest](const auto& p){ return p.passes(valToTest); }, var); });
```

This code is concise but rather hard to read (and to format). Particularly the nested lambda isn't great. It does have the advantage that the result can be `const`.
**Is there any way to get rid of the nested lambda or make this more readable?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to hide away the complexity in a function or class. One possibility is to create a function that returns the nested lambda, like so:

```
static auto passes(auto valToTest) {
    return [valToTest](const auto& var) {
        return std::visit([&valToTest](const auto& p) {
            return p.passes(valToTest);
        }, var);
    };
}

const bool allPassed3 = std::ranges::all_of(predicates, passes(valToTest));
```

There are other ways to reduce the amount of lambdas perhaps, like using `std::bind` and/or creating a class that has an `operator()`, but in the end that will probably be equally or even more hard to read as lambdas are basically shorthand for that.

Comment: That's what I feared. The idea of giving the lambdas a concise name is good, I settled on a local variable instead of a function.